# Dynamic/Personalised link in Email Studio

Tags: ampscript, email, dynamic, email-studio, einstein-recommendations

I'm trying to send out a survey email using dynamic survey link to different people. What would be the ideal way to achieve this? Do I just upload it to DE and use AMPScript?

[image: Table]

Thanks

Comment: It totally depends on your subscriber key. If it is the email address, then you should be fine just creating a sendable data extension with the above fields, and use it as a destination for your email.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the survey links are in a data extension related to the sending audience by email address, then you can use the [**lookupRows**](https://ampscript.guide/lookuprows) function.  `EmailAddr` is a [**system string**](https://ampscript.guide/system-strings) that exists for every email send.

Assuming your survey data extension is named `SubscriberSurveyData`:

```ampscript
%%[

var @rows, @row, @rowCount, @emailAddr, @i

set @emailAddr = AttributeValue("emailAddr")
set @rows = LookupRows("SubscriberSurveyData","emailAddr", @emailAddr)
set @rowCount = rowcount(@rows)

output(concat("emailAddr: ", @emailAddr))

if @rowCount > 0 then

  for @i = 1 to @rowCount do

    set @row = row(@rows, @i)
    set @LastName = field(@row,"LastName")
    set @FirstName = field(@row,"FirstName")

    ]%%

    <br>Row %%=v(@i)=%%
    <br>FirstName: %%=v(@FirstName)=%%
    <br>LastName: %%=v(@LastName)=%%
    <br>link: %%=v(@link)=%%

    %%[

  next @i ]%%

%%[ else ]%%

  No survey found

  <!-- could also raiseError here and skip the send --> 

%%[ endif ]%%
```